# VSTS Extensions Vetting Process

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm looking into using VSTS as a build system and obviously one of the advantages to using it are the various extensions that are available from the Marketplace.

When extensions are submitted do they undergo any kind of vetting or review process to ensure no-one is doing anything they shouldn't?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Comment: As someone who watches the RSS feed and sees the junk that gets published on a regular basis, probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding private extensions, you need to [share to the VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/publish/overview#share) by Click Share Button and the extension can be installed to the related VSTS, there isn’t the strict process to verify it.

However, if you need to make it publish, only verified publishers can have public items on Marketplace, Microsoft might also request a demo and to review the content planned for your Marketplace entry.

The process to have a public VSTS listing:[Make your extension or integration public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/publish/publicize)